# Unable to determine if device supports UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I am currently using Windows 10 in MBR disk partition mode, when I check the system information it says "Legacy", I want to install a fresh Windows and a Linux distro side by side in UEFI mode.

However there is no option in my BIOS settings to disable the Legacy mode or turn on UEFI mode. (My BIOS is InsydeH20, searching on the net I found that other users using the same BIOS have some options regarding UEFI and Legacy mode)

To check if my BIOS supports the UEFI mode I did several things:

1. I wanted to update my BIOS to see if the options appear after updating the BIOS. On the support [page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-dv6-6000-entertainment-notebook-pc-series/5048664/model/5062494) of my laptop, there is an application called HP BIOS Update UEFI and another HP System Diagnosis UEFI, when I use it, it creates a partition called HP_Tools and inside it there are several .efi files. I am able to access this tool by pressing F2 after turning on my laptop. However in boot options, no UEFI or Legacy options were added.
2. I read somewhere that recent Linux systems use UEFI/GPT mode, I downloaded the latest Fedora Tumbleweed live usb and created a USB using DD mode in Rufus, during my research I read somewhere in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios) that if my bios supports UEFI mode there will be a folder present  `/sys/firmware/efi`, in the root of my system. I found this folder.

However when I use Rufus to create a "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" Windows Installation USB, it fails to boot it and runs my currently installed Windows.
I tried creating both FAT32 and NTFS USBs and both fail to boot the installation media.

To my understanding UEFI is a booting mode and GPT is a disk mode.

1. If my system runs the EFI files of the HP Diagnosis Tool and Linux, can I assume that my system supports UEFI booting mode?
2. If yes why the settings for Legacy mode and Secure Boot not present when I am in my BIOS settings and I am unable to boot the GPT Windows Installation USB?

The problem is I want to install Linux and Windows side by side and want both of them to run in the same mode (UEFI/GPT). How can I achieve this?

UPDATE: Link to [specs](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02776800). BIOS: InsydeH20 F.1B or F.13 (Both can be downloaded on the drivers page, and I have tried both with no luck.)

UPDATE 2: Inside the HP_TOOLS created partition by HP BIOS Update UEFI and another HP System Diagnosis UEFI there are is one only one folder called Hewlett-Packard. Inside this folder there are two folders with these content:

[BIOSUpdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVuLj.jpg)
[SystemDiags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxD8K.jpg)

Update 3: [win7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtCVL.jpg)
[softwares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuzI4.jpg)
[softwares 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEVtW.jpg)

see the rest here ( i dont have enough rep)
   `https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWhqi.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKNAG.jpg
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAQZr.jpg
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyf5P.jpg
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/doFHq.jpg
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/qej91.jpg`

Comment: Not sure why @ramhound deleted his answer. I tried to comment that there may be a UEFI firmware update, but last I remember trying this it didn’t work as expected and there were some caveats. Better read up on it first. Why not provide the model of your system as was requested?

Comment: @Ramhound I adeed some photos, you can also search for : HP Pavilion dv6-6080se Entertainment Notebook PC

Comment: @Ramhound about HP being unfriendly I totally agree with you, I have been searching their forum for one day to solve this problem. They ask for specs and things like that, and suddenly stop the conversation or tell you to call HP Support. Some people have had this problem too, but no one had answered them in HP Support Forums.

Comment: I was being overrun by notifications so I deleted my comments.  My research is indicating the tools in question are not applicable to your device, despite them being in the list of software that is supposed to be for your device.  There are operating systems listed for those tools, that have never supported UEFI, so all those tools do is create an EFI partition which any operating system can do.

Comment: Thanks. But when I delete this partion and hit F2 after turning on the device, it shows basic dos diagnosis. But then use this tool and create this partition and hit F2, there is a GUI diagnosis page, which saves the log files again in this efi partition. So when my BIOS can access this efi partition, doesn't it mean that it supports it? That's what is confusing.

Comment: The EFI partition is just a FAT32 partition, and the HP tools require a FAT32 partition with a specific name, the fact log files are being generated doesn't mean your device supports UEFI.  The fact you cannot disable legacy mode, means, it does not.  It actually means your device has BIOS-based firmware, which is entirely different than a UEFI based firmware, UEFI based firmware can provide legacy support (i.e. support legacy actions that are only supported by BIOS).